# Null Object pattern with a MyBatis TypeHandler

Tags: java, mybatis, typehandler

I have been trying to make a custom `TypeHandler` in MyBatis so that for a `null` column in the database, MyBatis returns an implementation of a [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) instead of having a `null` in the domain class.

After *googling* for help, I reached the excelent project [mybatis-koans](https://github.com/midpeter444/mybatis-koans), namely the [koan 19](https://github.com/midpeter444/mybatis-koans/blob/master/src/main/java/net/thornydev/mybatis/koan/koan19/Koan19.java) that addresses exactly this issue with the same approach I am using, i.e., extending `BaseTypeHandler<T>` (is abstract). At this point, I have a concrete `TypeHandler` similar to the [`EmailTypeHandler` in that koan](https://github.com/midpeter444/mybatis-koans/blob/master/src/main/java/net/thornydev/mybatis/koan/util/EmailTypeHandler.java):

```
/**
 * Acts as a factory method to return the appropriate implementation of an Email.
 * Returns a Null object if the email value in the database was null/empty
 */
public class EmailTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Email> {

  @Override
  public Email getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String colName) throws SQLException {
    return createEmail(rs.getString(colName));
  }

  @Override
  public Email getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int colNum) throws SQLException {
    return createEmail(rs.getString(colNum));
  }


  private Email createEmail(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    if (s == null || s.equals("")) {
      return new NullEmail();
    } else {
      return new EmailImpl(s);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Email getNullableResult(CallableStatement arg0, int arg1) throws SQLException {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int colNum,
                                  Email e, JdbcType t) throws SQLException {
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the author (*midpeter444*) is facing the same problem: when the value in the DB is `null`, null is still returned instead of the object crafted in the concrete `TypeHandler`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw the solution right after posting the question. In [BaseTypeHandler](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/BaseTypeHandler.java) code:

```
[...]
  public T getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    T result = getNullableResult(rs, columnName);
    if (rs.wasNull()) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  }

  public T getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    T result = getNullableResult(rs, columnIndex);
    if (rs.wasNull()) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  }

  public T getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    T result = getNullableResult(cs, columnIndex);
    if (cs.wasNull()) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  }

  public abstract void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, T parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException;

  public abstract T getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException;

  public abstract T getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException;

  public abstract T getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException;
[...]
```

Clearly, `BaseTypeHandler` is going to return `null` when the value in the database is `null`, as `cs.WasNull()` is `true` in that case. Therefore, the solution is to create a concrete [`TypeHandler<T>`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/TypeHandler.java) returning the appropiate implementation (in this case, a NullObject implmentation when the value in the database is null) without subclassing `BaseTypeHandler`.

**EDITED** (folowing *quux00*'s comment): Of course, we can just override `getResult` method of `BaseTypeHandler`, given that the functionality provided by its method `setParameters` can be useful.

Comment: The beauty of open source - read the code for the answer. Nice analysis!  One critique - you could still subclass BaseTypeHandler and just override the getResult methods, no?  To implement TypeHander directly, you'll also have to implement setParameters, which for this case could just be a no-op, but in other scenarios you may want the functionality provided by `BaseTypeHandler#setParameters`.

Comment: Your are right... It's better just to override `getResult` method to use the provided `setParameter` method in `BaseTypeHandler`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer!  It helped me understand my problem and how to overcome it.  I wanted a result to never be null.

By you posting the code for `BaseTypeHandler`, it confirmed that null was being returned depending on `ResultSet.wasNull` and not on the result itself returned from `getNullableResult`.  So I overrode `getResult` in the concrete subclass of `BaseTypeHandler`.  In the custom implementations of `getResult`, `super.getResult` is called, and then null is checked for.  Below is an example:

```
public Money getResult ( ResultSet rs, String columnName ) throws SQLException
{
    Money result = super.getResult ( rs, columnName );
    return result == null ? Money.ZERO : result;
}

public Money getResult ( ResultSet rs, int columnIndex ) throws SQLException
{
    Money result = super.getResult ( rs, columnIndex );
    return result == null ? Money.ZERO : result;
}

public Money getResult ( CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex ) throws SQLException
{
    Money result = super.getResult ( cs, columnIndex );
    return result == null ? Money.ZERO : result;
}
```