# MyBatis special result when select returns no rows

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, mybatis

My MyBatis select is

```
 // result map that sub-selects a folder
 <resultMap id="beanWithFolderMap" type="com.example.BeanWithFolder">
    <id column .../>
    <association column="folder_id" property="folder" javaType="com.example.Folder" select="selectFolder"/>
 </resultMap>


 // folder sub-select
 <select id="selectFolder" resultType="com.example.Folder">
        SELECT

        folder_id
        name,

        FROM folders
        WHERE folder_id=#{folderId}
 </select>
```

When no rows matching folder_id are found I want to return a special instance of Folder class.

Right now MyBatis returns null when it can't find a row. I want to return a Folder instance with folderId field set - since I know what I'm looking for I can at least set this field.

How to do it?

---

something like

```
        SELECT

        #{folderId} as folder_id,
        name,

        FROM folders
        WHERE folder_id=#{folderId}
```

would be great, but I get the exception "Could not determine data type of parameter $1"

Comment: can you show us the code which calls the select statement?

Comment: what exactly would you need?

Comment: the code snippet, which calls your second select.

Comment: or better the code snippet, which calls your first sql from your application.

Comment: perhaps what I added is enough? I'd focus on my "wishful" solution - is it possible to "select" a value?

Comment: Using a Null Object Pattern with a MyBatis TypeHandler coud be an option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874547/null-object-pattern-with-a-mybatis-typehandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Function

If this query is used frequently, I would create a small function for it. That's probably fastest:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_foo(_folder_id int)
  RETURNS TABLE (folder_id int, name text) AS
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
SELECT f.folder_id, f.name
FROM   folders f
WHERE  f.folder_id = $1;

IF NOT FOUND THEN       -- only if nothing was found
    RETURN QUERY
    VALUES ($1, NULL);  -- columns must match!
END IF;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_foo(133)
```

That's what you use in your script. Just like selecting from a table.

#### Plain SQL

There are other ways with plain SQL, preferably using `NOT EXISTS`. I guess a CTE would help:

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT folder_id, name
   FROM   folders
   WHERE  folder_id = $1;
   )
SELECT * FROM x
UNION  ALL
SELECT $1, NULL
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM x);
```

Comment: this is supported in PSQL? (both solutions)?

Comment: I like the second SQL, but I get an error *unexpected token: WHERE* refering to the last `where`. Using HSQL DB

Comment: @Prospolon: Both solutions are for PostgreSQL. The second one requires version 8.4+ for the CTE.

Comment: Ok, in HSQL I had to add a `FROM folders` between `SELECT $1 ...` and `WHERE ..`.